# Google 410 crawl errors for pages that never existed

Tags: google, search-engine-indexing

I managed to get my WordPress installation down to zero crawl errors, but recently the number of 410 errors has grown substantially:

[image: Google crawl errors]

What I can't grasp is why pages that don't exist keep getting added to the list.  The URLs seem to be recursive or something...

[image]

My .htaccess has the following redirects in place to try and deal:

```
RedirectMatch 410 blog/.*
RedirectMatch 410 2013/.*
RedirectMatch 410 2015/.*
RedirectMatch 410 drink/.*
RedirectMatch 410 feature/.*
RedirectMatch 410 meal/.*
RedirectMatch 410 portfolio/.*
RedirectMatch 410 sortable-3-col/.*
RedirectMatch 410 grid-3-col/.*
```

Could the random recursive URLs be caused by the wildcard redirect, or is this just Google weirdness?

Comment: When you click on the URLs in the list in that report, Google should tell you where it found the link.  What does it say?

Comment: Are those URLs similar to URLs you actually have on your site but with repeated portions?   If so that is often because of relative links in your header and footer.

Comment: Your screenshot says "Not found" but you say "410" which would be "Gone".  Do you mean "404 Not Found" errors?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller "Not Found" is from Google's Search Console. Only one of the pages is 404; remainder are 410. The URLs have terms that are not in any URL, header/footer content, or taxonomy. All links are from site root.